# Transitioning between React elements being rendered dynamically from an Object

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a React component that dynamically renders slides on the page from a `slides` object based on a state variable. I'd like to add some CSS transitions when the slides enter and exit, but I can't seem to find a good way to do it. Below is a simplified example of what I'm working with, but should get the idea across:

```
const slides = {
   slide1: {
      id: 1,
      content: <>Slide content</>,
      nextSlide: slide2,
      prevSlide: null
   },
   slide2: {
      id: 2,
      content: <>Slide content</>,
      nextSlide: slide3,
      prevSlide: slide1,
   },
   slide3: {
      id: 3,
      content: <>Slide content</>,
      nextSlide: null,
      prevSlide: slide2
   }
}

const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState("slide1")

return (
   <div>
      {slides[currentSlide].content}
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(slides[currentSlide].prevSlide}
         Previous Slide
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(slides[currentSlide].nextSlide}
         Next Slide
      </button>
   </div>
)
```

I've tried writing a handler function that sets the slide state change on a delay and then triggers a separate state variable that inject a CSS class name corresponding to some transition rules into the content container, but I couldn't get it working how I thought it would. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest to use react in-line styles and trigger the transiction directly from the state

Comment: try using [this](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group) library, it looks like what you need